# list out of range: when a line is appended to a list by searching a word in a file

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
file1 = open('manu.txt', 'r')
charlist = []
lines=file1.readlines()
for i in range(0,len(str(lines))-1):
    prevline=lines[i]
    nextline=lines[i+1]
    if 'a' in nextline:
        charlist.append(nextline)
print charlist
```

I am trying to find a word and trying to keep that in a list by reading each line a file. But it is giving list out range error.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I formatted your code so that it can be read more easily. Since this is python and your code did not contain any indentation please check that I guessed correctly. Additionally, please add the complete error message you get to your question using the edit function.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess your mistake is here:

```
for i in range(0,len(str(lines))-1)
```

Variable `i` iterates over length of `str(lines)` (which is string representation of the list), not `lines` itself. Try:

```
for i in range(0, len(lines) - 1)
```

instead?